# Replace a string in XSL SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepiont

In SharePoint Designer I have an xsl output that spits out the below as a string

```
 <div><font face="Arial Narrow" size="2">N/A</font></div>
```

I would like to replace "Arial Narrow" with "Arial".
Can this be done using some xsl functions?

Comment: Can you explain what you really mean? Typing "Verdana" or using find/replace does not work?

Comment: Hi teylyn I want to find "Arial Narrow" in that string and replace it with e.g another font type

Comment: So? You are using SharePoint Designer? Just type or use Ctrl-H for the Find/Replace dialog. Or are you not explaining what you really want to do?

Comment: No thats the output :) What i'm trying to replace is in xsl

<xsl:value-of select="@Insurance" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

Comment: So, maybe you want to edit your question and ask what you are really after. Why don't you describe the issue from the top. Pretend we cannot see your screen or read your mind.

Comment: Sorry for this.I kind of taught it was just an output string so it didn't matter to explain that much.Just wanted to see if its easier to use replace in xsl to replace the text Arial Narrow.Does this make sense now?

Comment: No, it does not make sense. Please edit your question instead of layering on stuff in comments. By now you should know how this site works. Explain what you have. Explain what you would like to have instead. Explain what you tried already.

Comment: Gosh, this is harder than pulling teeth. Posting the resulting html does not help at all if you want help on manipulating the xsl. Ever considered posting the xsl? And also provide some context for the xsl. Where does it originate? Did you write it? Is it generated by SharePoint? Is it in a DVWP? Is it in an XLV? What is the rest of the template? Are there font tags in the xsl? If not, how come you think changing the xsl will do any good?